# How can I use refs to set callbacks on a FlatList?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-ref

I'm trying to use `refs` to set the `onEndReached` prop of my FlatList imperatively. Is there a way to do that?

I've modified an [example from the PR](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/75508c1#commitcomment-35238666) PR that adds `setNativeProps` that toggles the color from black to white on an interval, but can't get `onEndReached` or `onScroll` to be called.

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

```
export default class Testing extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    let tick = 0
    this.list.setNativeProps({
      onEndReached: info => {
        // NEVER CALLED 
        console.log('L231 on Scroll info ===', info)
      },

      onScroll: info => {
        // NEVER CALLED 
        console.log('L250 info ===', info)
      },

      // Background DOES flash red on load...  
      style: { backgroundColor: 'red' }
    })
    setInterval(() => {
      this.list.setNativeProps({
        onEndReached: info => {
          console.log('L231 on Scroll info ===', info)
        },

        // Background DOES toggle black and white...  
        style: { backgroundColor: tick++ & 2 ? 'white' : 'black' }
      })
    }, 1000)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          ref={component => (this.list = component)}
          style={{ backgroundColor: 'black' }}
          data={[{ key: 'a' }, { key: 'b' }]}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

## Things I've Tried

#### Setting `onEndReached` directly on `this.list`

```
export default class Testing extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.list.onEndReached = info => {
        // NEVER CALLED 
        console.log(info)
    }
  }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? I dont think those are native props, you should be able to just do `this.list.onEndReached` without going into native props. You can look here to see what's available: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation

Comment: My ultimate goal is to create a library that uses hooks to create an infinite paging list where all the user has to do is supply a loading method and set the ref returned from the custom hook to their FlatList. The implications there are that I need to be able to set `onEndReached` and ultimately even be able to set the `data` prop on the FlatList imperatively. Does that make sense? I tried just setting this.list.onEndReached and that did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a very similar problem and one way I got around this was using Higher Order Components (HOCs). With HOCs, you can override any prop you want with minimal intrusion.

[HOC Example/Info](https://medium.com/@albertchu539/higher-order-components-in-a-react-hooks-world-69fe1f0b0791)

Comment: From Review: Please add some sample source code to your answer. Links to solutions are welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without them: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link [may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)